# Need help getting distance between start and destination via multiple waypoints

Tags: here-api

Im trying to calculate a totalt distance between start to destination via one or more waypoints.

`start0=geo!58.290221,12.348646&waypoint0=geo!passThrough!57.761150,14.166870&destination0=geo!57.696626,11.980591&mode=fastest;truck&summaryAttributes=distance`

Above is what im trying but I only seem to get the distance between start0 and destinaton0. Somehow it's skipping the waypoint.

Any pointers to what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work it out with the findsequence API.
start+destinaion0+destination1+...destinationX+end.

Only drawback (if you see it that way) is that the here api is optimizing the route distance and not the order you specifiy. 
Start and end will be first and last and all destinations inbetween will be routeoptimized.